# Filtering Data in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering

I am doing a demo project in React. All users are showing on my home page and I have put a filter on the home page in which I am filtering active and inactive users from all users.

My filtering is working fine for active and inactive users separately I mean when I run filter for active or inactive users at once my filter is working properly. But I want that when my users have been filtered for any status once(active or inactive), then I can run the filter for other status at the same time and at that time I got the results for that selected status only.

What's happening to me right now is that when I'm clicking on the second checkbox with already filtered results, I'm getting a blank page only.

Yes, one more thing that when I click on the checkbox of the filter it automatically closes the Dropdown while I want it not to be closed. I want that my Dropdown list should not be closed no matter how many times I click the checkbox. And by clicking on my different checkboxes, I can see the results of only the checked checkboxes at a time.

**Note**: I have taken Dropdown from Ant Design and checkbox from Material UI.

I hope I have explained my query well to you. Thank you.

Here is my code.

**contacts.jsx**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FilterListIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FilterList";
import { Dropdown } from "antd";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { Card, CardContent, CardMedia, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import users from "../constants/users";

const Contacts = () => {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState(users);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const result = usersList?.filter((user) =>
      user.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(userInput.toLowerCase())
    );
    setUsersList(result);
  };
  const isActive = () => {
    const result = usersList?.filter((user) => user.status === "active");
    setUsersList(result);
  };
  const isInActive = () => {
    const result = usersList?.filter((user) => user.status === "inactive");
    setUsersList(result);
  };

  const userStatus = (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox onChange={isActive} />}
        label="Active"
      />
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox onChange={isInActive} />}
        label="InActive"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
  
return (
    <div className="parentDiv">
      <div className="header">
        <h1>Robo Space</h1>

        <div className="headerItems">
          <input
            className="searchFilter"
            type="text"
            value={userInput}
            onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Search here"
            onKeyPress={handleSearch}
          />

          <span className="filterIcon">
            <Dropdown overlay={userStatus} trigger={["click"]}>
              <FilterListIcon />
            </Dropdown>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="body">
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={2}
          direction="row"
          justify="flex-start"
          alignItems="flex-start"
        >
          {usersList?.map((user) => {
            return (
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3} key={usersList?.indexOf(user)}>
                <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
                  <CardMedia
                    component="img"
                    height="140"
                    image={user.avatar}
                    alt="robo img"
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                      {user.first_name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                      {user.email}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <Link className="showMoreLink" to={`/${user.id}`}>
                    Show More
                  </Link>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Contacts;
```

Comment: Hey! I'm happy to look into it, could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with a working example? Then I can modify your code easily.
It looks like in `isActive()` and `isInActive()` you're "throwing" the filtered users away when calling `setUsersList()`, so the next time the list doesn't include the filtered values anymore, thus you're getting a blank page. 
Regarding the not closing, does googling `e.stopPropagation()` help?

Comment: picklepick, I have tried to make codesandbox, it is made something like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-mountain-6zeju

Comment: Mhh this example is not working at all for me, I can't select either checkbox. I will take a look though, but if you could get it to actually behave as you have it locally that would help a lot!

Comment: I will try to make it like that and I will share with you as soon as it is done.